# Javascript loop will not update itself

Tags: javascript

This code does not seem to run well: http://jsfiddle.net/5GEru/1/

```
var left = 0;
function mouvement(){
    var bouger = document.getElementById("bouge");    
    bouger.style.left= left;
    left++;

    mouvement();

}
window.onload = mouvement();​
```

The variable increments itself but somehow the left value does not get reapplied everytime the function is run. it remains at the initial 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your tips guys!

Comment: How would your code ever stop? Isn't this an infinite loop?

Comment: Probably a stack overflow error. Use `setTimeout()` to clear the stack, and also, give the browser a chance do reflow.

Comment: @hsalama it shouldn't :p

Comment: @SnippetSpace why? Isn't this a recursion without an end statement? What am I missing?

Comment: Also, cache the DOM reference *outside* of the function on page init, so that you don't have to query it on every function call.

Comment: @hsalama Was just not ready to add that yet. Here is the final result: http://jsfiddle.net/5GEru/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the browser with invalid CSS. The browser is looking for a unit.

Try:

```
bouger.style.left = left + "px";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add "px" to left.

```
bouger.style.left= left + "px";
```

Of course, it also runs so fast you can't see anything happen, so I have a modified version:

http://jsfiddle.net/5GEru/2/

Also, your code should terminate at some point. Like when left becomes greater than SOMETHING for example. If you're using jQuery of course, you could just do:

```
$(function(){
    $("#bouge").animate({"left": 500},2000);
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/5GEru/6/
    ​

Comment: since you got the answer first I guess you get the checkmark :). thanks!

Comment: @Nile beat me by a few seconds, actually. :) You can upvote though if this answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval()` to executes a function, over and over again,

Here's your updated code which uses `setInterval()`, http://jsfiddle.net/5GEru/4/

Also you need to add `px` in this line, `bouger.style.left= left+'px';`